# Bluetooth advertisement packet format restrictions

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

Are there any firm restrictions on the formatting of advertisement data and scan response data for Bluetooth Low Energy?

The sample projects I'm learning from start the advertisement data with some flag bytes and then the name of the device.  Both the flags and the name are also preceded by a length byte.

If I have an observer module that needs to keep track of another beacon module, can I make the beacon advertise any sort of gibberish that I want as long as the observer module knows what to look for, or does the beacon have to have some sort of logical arrangement of data in the advertisement?

Thanks

Comment: Are you planning to use the advertisement packet to communicate data? Aside from being something of a hack, I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with this.

Comment: Yes, it would be to encode status information for tracking without needing to make a connection.  I just don't want the Bluetooth SIG or the FCC to come knocking on my door for breaking some rule about data formatting haha.